# What are the best recources for learning .NET webservices?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net, web-services

I'd like to get up to speed on web services--

I've found that I really like the video format; I tend to skim when I'm reading (bad habit) and I generally don't get the full value out of the video.  I would like to see any kind of good resource that you can recommend though; the best thing to do is to collect the best resources.

Comment: How well do you understand web technologies generally?

Comment: in general, I am an experienced developer, but only on the desktop software side.  I've hit databases but only with the help of a DBA and teammates who wrote those layers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here are some good starts

- http://www.asp.net/learn/videos/video-280.aspx
- http://www.dnrtv.com/default.aspx?showNum=33
- http://www.pnpguidance.net/Screencast/DayOfPatternsPracticesScreencastWCSFAJAXDynamicDataMVCFramework.aspx
- http://www.pnpguidance.net/Screencast/CreateDataAccessLayerUsingDataAccessGuidancePackageScreencast.aspx

if you like screen cast these are the places to start looking, also look at http://www.dimecasts.net/, but they didn't have any on web services

Answer (score 1):

The [WCF Developer Center](http://msdn.microsoft.com/wcf) on MSDN is a good place to start.

Be sure to stay away from ASMX web services and WSE web services. They are old and obsolete, respectively.

Comment: thanks for the suggestion.  I was considering .NET 2.0 technologies, since that probably what most projects are using currently.

Comment: I have reason to believe you are mistaken about which technologies "most projects" are using. It's WCF, without a doubt. Recall that WCF was released in November 2006 and is basically on it's v2.0 now (with 3.0 coming within a year). Expect no enhancements to the ASMX technology, and few, if any, bug fixes. It's been quite thoroughly replaced by WCF.

Comment: to say WCF has replaced ASMX is kinda of wrong, seeing there for 2 uses. WCF is for inter application communication, for dealing with stuff where you control everything and ASMX is for publicly exposed web services

Comment: @Bob: I'm sorry, but you're totally wrong. If you have seen some URL that suggests that, then please post it here.

Answer (score 1):

You could check out the following tutorial:

http://quickstarts.asp.net/QuickStartv20/webservices/

I would also recommend learning more about web development and data access layers and since you said that the majority of your experience is on the desktop side.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to check out the WCF webservice world (and I would definitely recommend that), go check out Aaron Skonnard's many-parts intro at "Endpoint TV" on Channel9:

http://channel9.msdn.com/shows/Endpoint/

He has a lot of intro screencast tutorials from very basic to fairly advanced, he covers all of WCF, even the latest greatest REST interfaces and stuff - highly recommended!

Marc

Answer (score 0):

[Channel9](http://channel9.msdn.com/) is a good place to start. Also, the [Mix](http://videos.visitmix.com/) sites will be worth a look.